# modify a mysql "show" command?

Tags: mariadb

How do I write a query which takes the data from a "show" query and manipulate it?

In this specific instance, I need just one of the fields from "show slave status".

How do I do this?

> SELECT Slave_IO_State FROM (show slave status);

OR, how do I find out the underlying query for a "show" type command? I vaguely recall doing this in the past, but can't find any reference to it. Possibly an option in the mysql client? I tried logging the queries run, but that just showed the "show slave status".

Comment: for what reason You need this information?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like `$ mysql -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' | grep 'Slave_IO'`?

Comment: I have a monitoring tool that allows me to confirm that "X" is up - ping, snmp, database queries etc. - but the first column needs to be "0" for "Everything's good", "1" for "Warning", or "2" for Error. Yes, I realize I can do an ugly kludge to work around limitations, but I thought there'd be a better way. I want to use this to monitor the replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot use the result of `SHOW` commands as if they were tables. You can, however use the [Performance Schema Replication Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-replication-tables.html).

To get the Slave_IO_State, you have to take into account the following remarK.

> The **Slave_IO_State** and **Slave_SQL_Running_State** fields are not preserved. If needed, these values can be obtained from the process list by using the THREAD_ID column of the appropriate replication table and joining it with the ID column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA PROCESSLIST table to select the STATE column of the latter table.

Comment: just remark - replication tables available since 5.7, buy this unfortunate reason - could not be a solution for previous versions

Comment: Some `SHOW` statements suport very limited table-like behavior at the row level... e.g. `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'user%'` ... but in this case, I think you're right... unless it's output manipulation from the CLI itself that OP is thinking of.